# Make available my swagger APIs to be read through swagger-ui (new swagger-node project)

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-node-express

I am using the Swagger Node project with Express 4 to build my apis. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node

I can make my "swagger api" work, however I could not get expose my apis as JSON to be read by the Swagger-UI(https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui).

How can I achieve it? I know that the previous version I need to use the following method:
swagger.configureSwaggerPaths("", "/api-docs", "");

But with the changes in the project, I dont what to call..

Ty

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into swagger-tools offered by Apigee-127, i believe this is the best module for node/swagger integration